# Can't seem to install 64bit GCC with YUM

Tags: linux, 64-bit, yum, gcc

I type the following...

```
$ yum install gcc.x86_64
```

(by the way, is "gcc.x86_64" the right package for 64bit gcc?)

[...]
I get the following errors...
[...]

```
Total size: 16 M
Downloading Packages:
Running rpm_check_debug
ERROR with rpm_check_debug vs depsolve:
libstdc++-devel is needed by (installed) gcc-c++-4.1.2-48.el5.i386
libstdc++-devel is needed by (installed) gcc-c++-4.1.2-48.el5.i386
libstdc++ is needed by (installed) gcc-c++-4.1.2-48.el5.i386
libstdc++ is needed by (installed) gcc-c++-4.1.2-48.el5.i386
libstdc++ is needed by (installed) gcc-c++-4.1.2-48.el5.i386
libstdc++ is needed by (installed) gcc-c++-4.1.2-48.el5.i386
gcc is needed by (installed) gcc-c++-4.1.2-48.el5.i386
gcc is needed by (installed) gcc-c++-4.1.2-48.el5.i386
Complete!
(1, [u'Please report this error in https://bugzilla.redhat.com  
/enter_bug.cgi?product=Red%20Hat%20Enterprise%20Linux%205&component=yum'])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to remove the `i386` builds of GCC to install the `x86_64` builds. I'm not sure why you have the `i386` build of GCC installed on a 64-bit OS -- it just messes things up. (In this case, the platform refers to the platform it is compiled to run *on*, not the platform it compiles *for*.)

You need to remove `gcc-c++-4.1.2-48.el5.i386` and replace it with the corresponding x86_64 package. You can either do it in one `yum` transaction or remove all dependent packages and then let `yum` reinstall them based of the correct `gcc` and `gcc-c++` packages.

You will need the `i386` (or `i686`) package of `libgcc` as well as the `x86_64` one. You need the `libgcc` for the target platform since it gets linked into the binaries gcc produces.